# listView.SelectedItemPosition return -1 always

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to get the position of the clicked item in a ListView in Xamarin, but using `SelectedItemPosition` returns -1 always.

```
ListView lsvSearch;
List<SearchResultItem> searchResults;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle){
    ...
    lsvSearch = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lsvSearch);
    lsvSearch.ItemClick += LsvSearch_ItemClick;
    ...
}
private void LsvSearch_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    ....
    Bundle valuesForActivity = new Bundle();
    valuesForActivity.PutInt("placeId", searchResults[lsvSearch.SelectedItemPosition].resultId); // lsvSearch.SelectedItemPosition always returns -1

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AboutPlace));
    ....
}
```

How can I solve this problem? How can I get the clicked item position instead of -1?

Comment: Don't know much about xamarin, but if it always returns -1, then I assume that you are using the wrong property.  I would look for a something like SelectedIndex.  Position just doesn't sound right to me.  The term "position" usually has to do with UI and "Index" is generally used to for any select an item from an IEnumerable object.  Good luck my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your `AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs` argument. It contains a lot of useful information, checkout the reference for that class here: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.AdapterView+ItemClickEventArgs/

For your specific issue, if you want the position of the selected item then use this: `e.Position`.

```
private void LsvSearch_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    ....
    Bundle valuesForActivity = new Bundle();
    valuesForActivity.PutInt("placeId", searchResults[e.Position].resultId); // lsvSearch.SelectedItemPosition always returns -1

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AboutPlace));
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms it is possible to access the selected index like this:

```
int index = lsvSearch.SelectedIndices[0];
```

This only works if `MultiSelect` is set to `false`! Otherwise it will give you only the first index.

Another possibility seems to be:

```
int index = lsvSearch.FocusedItem.Index;
```

Please try it and comment whether it works also in Xamarin. I'll be waiting. (otherwise I delete this answer)